# How to mock python and shell scripts in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I've to run python and shell scripts in my node JS code. But to begin with, i've to mock the script calls. Is there any ways i can mock this python and shell scripts and send my expected response? Kindly share me your thoughts.

Below is the Code i use to call the script. When the PythonShell.run gets executed, i want to mock results and return my preferred response.

```
function callScript(){ 
            var options = {
            mode: 'text',
            pythonPath: 'path/to/python',
            pythonOptions: ['-u'],
            scriptPath: 'path/to/my/scripts',
            args: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
        };

        PythonShell.run('my_script.py', options, function (err, results) {
            if (err) throw err;
            // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution
            console.log('results: %j', results);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Share also the code you have until now so people can actually help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with sinon i am able to mock the script call(not only script, we can mock any complex logic) and send expected json repsonse.

```
var sinonSandbox =  sinon.sandbox.create();

sinonSandbox.stub(PythonShell,'run').withArgs(sinon.match.any, sinon.match.any, sinon.match.any).yields(<Json object>)
```

after execution:

```
sinonSandbox.restore();
```